# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys{})

Tags: reactjs

Can anyone help me to resolve following error?

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, type, compare, WrappedComponent, displayName}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

[image]

following  is my index.js file -

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { App } from './App';
import { store } from '../src/helpers/store';

import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>, 
    document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

**Update**

App.js looks like -

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import routes from "./routes";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./shards-dashboard/styles/shards-dashboards.1.1.0.min.css";

class App extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
          <Router basename={process.env.REACT_APP_BASENAME || ""}>
            <div>
              {routes.map((route, index) => {
                return (
                  <Route
                    key={index}
                    path={route.path}
                    exact={route.exact}
                    component={props => {
                      return (
                        <route.layout {...props}>
                          <route.component {...props} />
                        </route.layout>
                      );
                    }}
                  />
                );
              })}
            </div>
          </Router>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    state
  };
}

const connectedApp = connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
export { connectedApp as App };
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not pointing to any other file/component of `<App />`?

Comment: @SharathKumar - I couldn't get you exactly, I am newbie in React, can you please make it more clear?

Comment: What does `App.js` look like?

Comment: @DavinTryon - Please check updated question.

Comment: Try this - `export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App)`

Comment: Can you share the routes file? Or upload the entire project to Github(if possible) if you can and share the link?